# java.io.FileNotFoundException (Is a directory)

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

This is a piece of code, I am trying to read a project. I am sure the project exists in the following path but I don't know why I am getting the following exception:

```
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException()[567]: 
       java.io.FileNotFoundException "/home/XX" (Is a directory)
```

**Code:**

```
 IProject project;

 String projectLocation = "/home/XX";

 IProjectDescription description;

 description = project.getWorkspace().loadProjectDescription(new Path(projectLocation));

 project.create(description, new NullProgressMonitor());

 project.open(new NullProgressMonitor());

 project.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE,new NullProgressMonitor());
```

Comment: How does it behave when you use absolute path?

Comment: This is my linux absolute path.

Comment: You should be more specific and google before asking, especially SO-answered questions. I see an example of project creation in http://stackoverflow.com/a/7440936/1083704

Comment: But the answer was not useful to me. SO, I created the new question and now I got my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If /home/XX is the directory containing the project, the actual project file is /home/XX/.project, and that is the path you should be using.

According to the [Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IWorkspace.html) documentation, loadProjectDescription requires the path in the local file system of an existing project description file", not the folder containing it.

Comment: The project folder is not the project file. The project file is a file, not a folder, with the last component of its name ".project".

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand why you exactly mean. For example, you have a java project, it has a project file containing src,bin,.... Where is that ".project"?

Comment: Open the project folder with your favorite file navigator.

Comment: You are confusing yourself by using "project file" to refer to a folder, not a simple file with the name ".project", which is what the Eclipse documentation means by "project file". src, bin etc. have to be in a folder (aka directory). The .project file should be in the same folder as src, bin, etc. Some file viewing tools hide, by default, any file whose name begins with ".", so you may not see it.

Comment: Note that ls hides files whose names begin with "." unless you use "ls -a" or "ls -A".

Comment: Thanks, I used ls -a, and I can see that I have .cproject in XX, so why still it does not work?

Comment: Did you change the project file path in your program? If so, what happened?

Comment: Now, I am getting this exception: org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Resource 'XX' is not open